# php gd script not saving image properly

Tags: php, gd

I've got this script, which only saves the image at `$image`, and not the image at `$newimage_2.` Help?

```
<?php


$newimage_1 = imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);
$newimage_2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($newimage_1);

// print image to screen
header("content-type: image/jpeg");   
imagejpeg($image);
imagejpeg($newimage_2);
imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);
imagedestroy($newimage_2);

?>
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but `imagecopymerge` returns a bool and `imagecreatefromjpeg` takes a string.

Comment: @alexn - that's why i have imagejpeg afterwards

Comment: As alexn wrote imagecreatefromjpeg takes string (a "Path to the JPEG image") and it seems that your $newimage_1 is bool.

Comment: also, two imagejpeg() calls in one requests isn't going to work ...

Comment: @WideBlade: That's not relevant. alexn is right.

Comment: So- How can I save both images to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$source_file_path=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file_path);
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($source_file_path);
$newwidth=540;
$newheight=round(($height/$width)*$newwidth);
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
$target_file_path = "images/".$filewhereyouwanttosaveit;

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('imgs/copyright.png');
$watermarkwidth = imagesx($watermark);
$watermarkheight = imagesy($watermark);
$startwidth = ($newwidth - $watermarkwidth);
$startheight = ($newheight - $watermarkheight);
imagecopy($tmp,$watermark,$startwidth,$startheight,0,0,$watermarkwidth,$watermarkheight);
imagegif($tmp,$target_file_path);
```

you probably dont need the resizing but code may help you...

imagegif or jpg or png or some else

Comment: Thanks Man-exactly what i wanted!